# Trying to find HLSL Compiler

Tags: direct3d, hlsl, shader

Googling for "HLSL compiler" and a few things, I'm frustratingly unable to find where to look for a standalone HLSL compiler for D3D9 so I can tell which lines are causing problems.

I can't see anything in my SDK but perhaps it has a name I am not recognising?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HLSL compiler is called `fxc.exe` and is located in the DirectX SDK under Utilities.

The path on my system is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (February 2010)\Utilities\bin\x64\fxc.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

For HLSL Effects that you can use in XNA/DX (PS 2.0-3.0) you can try:

[3DPee (Tridipy) player and shader editor](http://marino.boletus.hr/)

It operates on images and video.
It supports multi pass technique, vertext shader, and has a nice editor with error message reporting on compile.
It's an alpha version i have developed but it can be useful.

Screenshot:
[image]